# Having issues getting entire output from StandardOutput.ReadToEnd

Tags: c#, psexec

At work we have a large number of on-site WES09 machines that are doing controls data gathering.  Because we have thousands of these, upgrades are a pain.  I have been slowly evolving a better process, and am currently working on a C# application to better manage these.

The machines are running File Based Write Filter, which has the effect that if PSEXEC had not been run on the machine before, it won't let it start.  So I use WMIC to disable FBWF.

I am trying to add a status feature to see if FBWF is enabled, as I haven't always had 100% success with WMIC.  Anyway, FBWF gives status output in the command window, but it's multiple lines.  It seems when I use StandardOutput.ReadToEnd, it only gets the first line.

So here is what it looks like when you check FBWF status from PSEXEC:

[FBWFOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX1qo.png)

When I run the C# Application I wrote, the output only gets this:

> "\r\nPsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely\r\nCopyright (C)
>   2001-2016 Mark Russinovich\r\nSysinternals -
>   www.sysinternals.com\r\n\r\nFile-based write filter configuration for
>   the current session:\r\n"

I don't know why it stops there, I can't get the rest of it that actually says if it is enabled or not (which is the next line, of course).

Here is the relevant code piece, leaving out IP/User/Pass:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\temp\PSTools\PsExec.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\" + RemotePCName + " -u " + Username + " -p " + Password + " fbwfmgr";

p.Start();

string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string errormessage = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

I thought my issue might be the line break, but there looks to be two between the PsExec portion and the FBWF output, but otherwise am not sure what else to try.  I spent a couple hours looking through other comments on issues with getting the output, but almost all were that the application would hang which is not an issue I am having.

Thank you in advance for the assistance, I am slowly learning C# and programming in general and this community has been a huge help!

Comment: Deadlock is a distinct possibility, given the volume of output and assuming the program ends normally.  So it doesn't make much sense to try to make code work that you know you must not write.  You do need to also check for error output.

Comment: I've checked the error output, it just shows that it is starting fbwfmgr and then fbwfmgr existed with error code -1, which is all normal and the same thing you get if running it locally.

Comment: So you got an error about fbwfmgr?  Isn't that exactly what you wanted to test for?

Comment: No, I need to know if FBWF is enabled or disabled, you get the same "Error" message regardless.  Just something with how FBWF was developed, but I have no control over that.  From everything I have found the ONLY way to find out its state is to get the line I put in the image in my original post where it says Enabled or Disabled.